# Javascript Iterate over .NET SerializedJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, json

NET guy here, so i'm very rusty at Javascript (or JQuery for that matter)

I serialized a list from server side .NET that i need to access on the client side.  The string result is in the following format.

```
[{"id":"1","name":"xxx"},{"id":"2","name":"yyy"}]
```

How do i iterate through this in Javascript? I'm having a hard time actually get the values in the array. I end up iterating through each character of the JSON string.

```
function BuildList() {

           var result = '<%= JSON %>';

           for (var obj in result) {
                alert("Obj: " + obj);
                for (var property in result[obj]) {
                    alert(property + "value: " + result[obj][property]);
                }
            }

       }
```

Comment: don't put the JSON variable in quotes `var result = <%=JSON%>;`

Comment: @jwatts1980: A nice idea, but not always ideal. It can mess up VS auto-formatting too.

Comment: @musefan: Agreed. I +1'd your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has built in function to convert JSON to a javascript object, try this:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext);
```

This code example was [taken from here](http://www.json.org/js.html), where you can read a lot more about it.

---

With your example, it could be used like so:

```
var result = '<%= JSON %>';
var resultObject = JSON.parse(result);
var firstId = resultObject[0].id;
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jVQz8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.parseJSON()` to parse the string literal to an object, and then you can loop through the properties of that object.

```
function BuildList() {
    var result = '[{"id":"1","name":"xxx"},{"id":"2","name":"yyy"}]';
    var resultObject = $.parseJSON(result);

    $.each(resultObject, function(key, value) {
         alert("Obj: " + + value.id + ' / ' + value.name);
    })
}

BuildList()
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sqVAT/)